# What's important when getting an artificial sunlight lamp?

Tags: environmental-climate, light, mood-moodiness, environmental-psychology

Artificial daylight lamps are frequently recommended as an intervention to improve mood in the winter months.

[image: daylight lamp in use]
<sup>[Image from Wikipedia](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Light_Therapy_for_SAD.jpg) and is licensed under the Creative Commons [Attribution-Share Alike 4.0 International license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en)</sup>

What's know about how they can be used the best way? Do we have knowledge that some lamps are better than others?

Comment: It's called full spectrum lighting. Sun lamps include ultra violet which you don't want.

Comment: Be sure you understand what you are getting . I had an excellent sun lamp that I ruined by using it with a dimmer.